# Show that for any $n$, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^k}\binom{n+k \log(3)/\log(2)}{k}=c 2^n$ for some constant $c$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory

I stumbled upon this from playing around and it seems to be true but I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Any $n$ integer? Did you try induction?

Comment: Ooh good idea and then c should be much easier to find if you pick n=0

Comment: If you make any progress, add it to the question to see how can we help.

Comment: Ah little typo, the sum should be from k=0 (this only matters when n=0).

Comment: OK I might as well explain how it came up. It's related to the '3x+1 problem'. OK first let's 'prove' the x-1 problem (replacing 3x+1 with x-1). The x-1 problem is equivalent to saying every number can be expressed as 2^n_1+2_n_2+...+2^n_k for some n_1 >...> n_k >=0. That's just saying every number can be expressed in binary. One way to prove that is with a counting argument, where you fix n_1=n and ask how many options there are. You get a sum over k of binom(n,k)=2^n. So that accounts for all the possible numbers up to 2^n. QED.

Comment: For the 3x+1 problem, the conjecture is equivalent to saying every number can be expressed as 2^n_1/3^k-2^n_2/3^k - 2^n_3/3^(k-1) - ... - 2^n_(k+1)/3 for some n_1 >...>n_(k+1) >=0. (Proving that equivalence is kinda fun.)
OK so now one big difference is that many of those numbers are not integers, so you only want to count some of them. That's where the factor of 1/3^k comes in (roughly). Also if you want to count the first 2^n numbers, you can't just set n_1=n, you need to set n_1=ceiling(n+k log(3)/log(2)).

Comment: What definition are you using for the binomial coefficient with a non-integer upper argument? Also, if there is a typo, then it should be fixed, not just commented on.

Comment: Ah thanks, fixed. I'm using the one with Gamma functions.

Comment: Well, as far as I see the conjecture is not true. Mathematica gives me $c=4.31879$ for $n=1$ and $c=4.56453$ for $n=2$. In general, $c$ seems to slowly increase.

Comment: Really? I'm using mathematica too and I'm getting the same value for n=1 and n=2 (around c=4.81884)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was summing from 1 instead of 0. And indeed the numbers are very close and the error would be just due to the working precision. But still, the proposition seems so improbable. Interesting problem.

Comment: I don't know where I had a problem. I prefer to delete my answer. Your number is correct. Cheers :-)

Comment: I think the details (especially the motivation) should go to the *question*, not stay in comments. I believe that's mostly why your question gets downvoted. No one likes tons of comments to read.

Answer (score 3):

Let $0 < b < 2$, $0 < a < 2^{-b}$, and $t > 0$. We will evaluate the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \binom{bk + t}{k}$$
and will use the result to prove @Bartek's conjecture.

Recall that for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, the function $z \mapsto z^\alpha := e^{\alpha \log z}$, where $\log$ denotes the principal branch of the logarithm, is defined and holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$, and satisfies $z^{\alpha + \beta} = z^\alpha z^\beta$ and $z^{k\alpha} = (z^\alpha)^k$ when $k$ is a positive integer. For $\alpha > 0$, we can define $z^\alpha = 0$ at $z = 0$ by continuity, and we have
$$(1 + z)^\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} z^n$$
on the closed unit disk, and the series converges absolutely there (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Convergence)). Using this expression, one can write
$$\binom{\alpha}{n} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{(1 + z)^\alpha}{z^{n+1}} \,dz$$
where $C$ is the unit circle, with a small indent to avoid the point $z = -1$. This means
$$\binom{bk + t}{k} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{(1 + z)^{bk+t}}{z^{k+1}} \,dz.$$
Now, assuming the indent of $C$ is small enough so that $r \leq |z| \leq 1$ on $C$ for some $r > 2^b a$, we have $|\frac{a(1+z)^b}{z}| \leq r^{-1}2^b a < 1$ on $C$, hence the series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k (1 + z)^{bk+t}}{z^{k+1}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1 + z)^t}{z}\left(\frac{a(1 + z)^b}{z}\right)^k = \frac{\frac{(1+z)^t}{z}}{1 - \frac{a(1+z)^b}{z}} = \frac{(1+z)^t}{z - a(1 + z)^b}$$
converges absolutely on $C$, uniformly, and thus we have
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{(1+z)^t}{z - a(1 + z)^b} \,dz = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{a^k(1 + z)^{bk+t}}{z^{k+1}} \,dz = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \binom{bk+t}{k}.$$
It remains to evaluate the integral on the left. Note that $(1 + z)^t$ and $z - a(1 + z)^b$ are holomorphic on an open set containing $C$ and its interior.

**Lemma**: $z - a(1 + z)^b$ has a unique zero $r$ in the closed unit disk, and this satisfies $0 < r < 1$.

*Proof*: Suppose $z_0$ is a zero in the closed unit disk. Clearly $z_0$ cannot be negative or zero. Let $\arg : \mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0] \to (-\pi, \pi)$ denote the argument function. Note that for $c > 0$ we have $\arg(cz) = \arg(z)$, $|\arg(c + z)| \leq |\arg (z)|$, and if $c \arg (z) \in (-\pi, \pi)$, then $\arg (z^c) = c \arg (z)$. Also note that when $|z| = 1$, $\arg(1 + z) = \frac{1}{2} \arg(z)$. Using these facts, we have
\begin{align*}
|\arg(1 + z_0)| 
&= |\arg(1 - |z_0| + (|z_0| + z_0))| \\
&\leq |\arg(|z_0| + z_0)| \\
&= |\arg(1 + z_0/|z_0|)| \\
&= (1/2)|\arg(z_0)|
\end{align*}
which is less than $\pi/2$, hence since $b < 2$, we have
$$|\arg(a(1 + z_0)^b)| = b|\arg(1 + z_0)| \leq \frac{b}{2} |\arg(z_0)|$$
which is strictly less than $|\arg(z_0)|$ when $\arg(z_0) \neq 0$, so in that case we cannot have $z_0 = a(1 + z_0)^b$. Thus any zero must be positive real. But $x - a(1+x)^b$ has positive derivative on $[0, 1]$, and is negative at $x = 0$ and positive at $x = 1$, so there is a unique $r$ in $(0, 1)$ with $r - a(1+r)^b = 0$. *[end proof.]*

One can check that the residue of $\frac{(1+z)^t}{z - a(1+z)^b}$ at $z = r$ is $\frac{(1 + r)^t}{1 - ab(1 + r)^{b-1}} = \frac{(1+r)^t}{1 - \frac{br}{1+r}} = \frac{(1+r)^{t+1}}{1 + r - br}$, and since $z = r$ is the unique pole of this function in $C$, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \binom{bk+t}{k} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{(1+z)^t}{z - a(1 + z)^b} \,dz = \frac{(1+r)^{t+1}}{1 + r - br}.$$

We can also run this process backwards: for $0 < r < 1$, and a given $0 < b < 2$, $\frac{r}{(r+1)^b}$ is a strictly increasing function of $r$, so $\frac{r}{(r+1)^b} < \frac{1}{(1+1)^b} = 2^{-b}$, and thus setting $a = \frac{r}{(r+1)^b}$, so $r = a(1+r)^b$, by the above we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{r}{(r+1)^b}\right)^k \binom{bk+t}{k} = \frac{(1+r)^{t+1}}{1 + r - br}.$$
Because $\frac{r}{(r+1)^b}$ is increasing on $[0, 1]$, we can take the limit as $r \to 1$ of both sides, giving
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-bk} \binom{bk+t}{k} = \frac{2^{t+1}}{2-b}$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too long for a comment but if we consider a function:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k{bk+x \choose k}$$
Then because of the identity:
$${n+1 \choose k}={n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1}$$
We have the following:
$$f(x+1)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k{bk+x+1 \choose k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\left[{bk+x \choose k}+{bk+x \choose k-1}\right]=f(x)+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^{k+1}{bk+x+b \choose k}=f(x)+af(x+b)$$
Which is a functional equation that would be perfectly satisfied by the family:
$$f(x)=c \cdot d^x$$
Of exponential functions where the exponent $d$ would have to satifsy:
$$d=1+ad^b$$
Which in fact is satisfied by $d=2$ when $a=\frac{1}{3}$ and $b=\log_23$. This equation seems however to not be enough to determine the function uniquely (even if we have that $f$ is increasing and continuous which should be easy to prove). 
**EDIT** 
After playing with the expression for a while I've noticed that although in general $f$ behaves exponentially only asymptotically when $d=2$ is the solution (equivalently when $a=2^{-b}$) $f$ becomes actually exponential. Moreover, the constant seems to be equal to $\frac{2}{2-b}$. Thus, I conjecture:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-bk}{bk+x \choose k} = \frac{2^{x+1}}{2-b}$$
For all real $x$ and all $0 \le b \le 2$ (outside this interval the sum does not converge).

Comment: Fantastic. That shows that a c exists right?

Comment: If you (or anyone) would like to try to turn this into a result for the 3x+1 conjecture you can email me at palmer@maths.ox.ac.uk

Comment: @Sam Well, not exactly. For example for $b=2$ and $a=\frac{1}{5}$ we have $d=\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ but $f(1)=\frac{-7+5\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $f(2)=\frac{-27+15\sqrt{5}}{2}$ so in particular $f(2)=df(1)$ does not hold (in fact Mathematica gives $f(x)=\, _2F_1\left(\frac{x+1}{2},\frac{x+2}{2};x+1;\frac{4}{5}\right)-1$ which is not exponential). But it seems to be true that the ratio $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}$ does indeed approach $d$ as $x$ tends to infinity.